# why should we bind a key to a memory block by pthread_setspecific rather than just keep the pointer to that block?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

As usual, we use `pthread_setspecific` to bind a dynamically allocated block to a global key.

```
void do_something()
{
    //get thread specific data
    int* glob_spec_var = pthread_getspecific(glob_var_key);
        *glob_spec_var += 1;
}

void* thread_func(void *arg)
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 1;
    pthread_setspecific(glob_var_key, p);
    do_something();
    pthread_setspecific(glob_var_key, NULL);
    free(p);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

However, if I simplify `thread_func` to this:

```
void do_something(int* p)
{
    //get thread specific data
    int* glob_spec_var = p; //pthread_getspecific(glob_var_key);
        *glob_spec_var += 1;
}

void* thread_func(void *arg)
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 1;
    // pthread_setspecific(glob_var_key, p);
    do_something(p);
    // pthread_setspecific(glob_var_key, NULL);
    free(p);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

It will do exactly the same thing with the last version. the pointer `p` is also different in each thread. So why do we have to bind the memory to a key, rather than just keep the pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed implement your own thread-specific storage by allocating it within the thread start function, then passing a pointer to it to every thread function, and freeing it on thread exit.

The advantage of the `pthread_setspecific()` / `pthread_getspecific()` interface is that it lets you avoid that bookkeeping - in particular, the need to pass that pointer to your thread-specific storage down through all of your code paths in case some leaf function needs it is quite onerous.

It also means that library code can access thread-local storage without requiring the library user to set it up and pass it in to the library on every call.

Comment: Also `thread_local` without the `pthread_setspecific()` faff ?